# scroll on absolute object in console like list

Tags: html, css

I have a list with commands that if a new one gets added (by angular code), it will be visible on the bottom and the overflow goes to the top, just like a console.

This is what I currently have:

```html
<div style="border: 2px solid #000000; height: 200px; width: 300px; position: relative; overflow-x: auto;">
        <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0;">
            <p>oldest</p>
      <p>Test</p>
      <p>Test</p>
      <p>Test</p>
      <p>Test</p>
      <p>Test</p>
      <p>Test</p>
      <p>Test</p>
      <p>Test</p>
      <p>Test</p>
      <p>Test</p>
      <p>latest</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

It does work like I want it to, but with this setup I can't scroll anymore to old commands. I know hot to get the scroll bar to show again but this will just destroy the overflow to the top..

Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: Does replacing `<div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0;">` with  `<div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0;height: 100%;">` solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you will have to set the height of the inner div to be 100% of its parent and enable the scrolling on that element. Something like this:

```js
$('div').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#scroll-div p").last().offset().top
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="border: 2px solid #000000; height: 200px; width: 300px; position: relative; overflow-x: auto;">
        <div id="scroll-div"  style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; height: 100%;width: 100%">
            <p>oldest</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>latest</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>latest</p>
            <p>latest</p>
            <p>latest</p>
            <p>latest2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Edit: If you want to scroll to the latest element of your container you will need either JavaScript or jQuery to scroll at the bottom of the element. I just added a jQuery function for that which you can see below. Hope that helps :)

Comment: yeah but when I do that, the scroll bar is just on the top again. I slowly thing I need js and always scrol to the bottom after a new one gets added :/

Comment: @sirzento Probably yes. I just updated the answer if you want to have a look on it.